# Flutter official examples ( bottom sheets & general questions )

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter and currently rewriting an existing Ionic / JS hybrid app with it. I must say its great, I like the more code oriented layout approach because I in fact am no web dev and doing CSS is not my thing.
Anyways, I am trying to figure out what actually is official documentation and where official examples reside.
I was able to use
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/google-maps-in-flutter
to add my map, now I am trying to add a bottom drawer and am little confused. There seem to be some form of standard bottom-sheet components
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html
and
https://m3.material.io/components/bottom-sheets/overview

but what I can not stich together in my head is why the first link only shows api docs without an image or example how it could look like and whether the second link is this exact sheet, but since both pages are not cross linked they appear to be independent of each other?
How can I create the sheets in the second link with code from the first link? I am trying to recreate the google maps look more or less.
Again, I started this not even a week ago, so things are just falling into place.

Comment: The first link is the flutter reference and the second one is Material Design reference, they have nothing to do with each other, since one can implement material design without flutter.

Comment: Here is a link that can help you better : https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html

Comment: Thanks, I had found that link right after posting. But it seems that I have to build the sheet myself, it does not come with that handle line for instance. Must read on, but thanks for both responses, makes more sense now.

Comment: I'll translate my comment to an answer. To mark this as answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first link is the flutter reference and the second one is Material Design reference, they have nothing to do with each other, since one can implement material design without flutter.
Here is a link that can help you better :

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ScaffoldState/showBottomSheet.html

Comment: Congrats on the 20karma points, thanks :)